# how can I get the index of rows having null values in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, null

I'd like to get index of rows which have only null values straight in pandas, python3.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
i = df.index[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
```

If large DataFrame, slowier solution:

```
i = df[df.isna().all(axis=1)].index
```

**Sample**:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[np.nan,0,1], 
                 "b":[np.nan,1,np.nan]}) 

print (df)
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  1.0
2  1.0  NaN

i = df.index[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
print (i)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

**Explanation**:

First compare missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
print (df.isna())
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
```

Then check if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.isna().all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

And last filter index values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: thanks! ill accept your answer in 8 minutes as expected!